# Google Maps Javascript API V3 - Want to add a marker and return the LatLng of the marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a question relevant to Google Maps API. I am learning how to use the Google Maps API. I can just show the map in the div tag, but what I want is to be able to click on the map and show the marker and return the LatLng of the clicked point.

```
function initialize(v_lat,v_long,v_place) {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
   var myOptions = {
         zoom: 15,
         center: latlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
   };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(   document.getElementById("map_canvas")       ,   myOptions   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the click event example

where you click on map marker place on that point and click on marker which will return the latlng of that location.

try this

```
var marker;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
   if(marker==null){
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng, 
          map: map,
          title:"Hello World!"
       });
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             alert("latlng" + marker.getPosition());
       });

   }
});
```

here is the link for google map v3 you can find all tutorials related to the map

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html